# Sizing Or range tbl_regression

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am experimenting with the plot() function in tbl_regression. I think it is a great addition to the package. However, I am wondering if it would be possible to customize the OR range that is shown on the plot.
For example, my plot is showing the 1,2,3 ORs and nothing below 1. But what if I want to specify the plot in such a way to show a tick at 1.5 with the number. Something like this in ggplot:
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 3, by = 0.3))

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example, aka a reprex. This will include both code and data.